# Compile and run an old Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular

I need to compile and old Angular project with these dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.3",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/material": "^6.3.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.9",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.9",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "npmlog": "^4.1.2",
        "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.8",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.9",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "codelyzer": "~4.4.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "prettier": "^1.16.4",
        "protractor": "^5.3.2",
        "ts-node": "~8.0.3",
        "tslint": "~5.8.0",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2"
    }
```

I'm using Nodejs version 8.9.4 and the npm install command works well; however, when I run ng serve command, I have this message:

```
ng serve
Node.js version v8.9.4 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

According to this https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3 table, angular-cli ~6.0.8 works with Nodjs 8.9.4.

But ok, I have installed Nodejs v14.15; ng serve list tons of errors; for example:

```
$ ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.6) is greater than your local version (6.0.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
                                                                                          
Date: 2022-09-02T09:56:14.497Z
Hash: 39187bc129a2ef15b208
Time: 10705ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 162 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 250 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 17.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.53 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (83)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0
    at module.exports (/home/myuser/Desktop/works/dir1/fram1xyz/source/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/Desktop/works/dir1/fram1xyz/source/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (/home/myuser/Desktop/works/dir1/fram1xyz/source/frontend/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:24:22)
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (83)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0
    at module.exports (/home/myuser/Desktop/works/dir1/fram1xyz/source/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/Desktop/works/dir1/fram1xyz/source/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (/home/myuser/Desktop/works/dir1/fram1xyz/source/frontend/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:24:22)
```

What I have to do to start the framework?!?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm for that. Just install it and type something like `nvm install 8.9.4` when you now write `nvm use 8.9.4` you basically are in that environment. Here you can run `npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.9`. Remember to switch it whenever you want to use that environment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using nvm to switch to different nodejs versions, but I have the problem written above when runnig the project. Why should I install the angular-cli v6.0.9 globally? The project is running its local cli.

Comment: maybe for nvm 8 it somehow installed a higher angular cli globally and wants to use this one. So by installing the angular cli with fixed version it might use the globally installed one. It is worth a shot I would say.

Comment: Try to add inside the package.json in scripts section this:
"start": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --o",

Comment: Thank you everybody; strange behavior, but I solved simply deleting the node_modules directory and reinstalling it!